# How to update table1 column from table3, with matching id from table2

Tags: mysql, join, update, table

I have 3 tables - customer, garages, the_cars. With columns like

```
customer           garages                  the_cars
id | car       owner_id | the_car_id       car_id | car
```

and need to update the_cars.car with customer.car if customer.car is null, and based by ids. Where customer.id matches with garages.owner_id, find by its garages.the_car_id the the_cars.car_id, and by it finally get the_cars.car and put into customer.car

the code I tried is, don't judge strictly, I'm new to this kind of sql queries

```
UPDATE `customer` 
SET `customer`.`car` = `the_cars`.`car` 
WHERE (`customer`.`car` IS NULL) 
AND (`customer`.`id` = `garages`.`owner_id`)
AND (`garages`.`the_car_id` = `the_cars`.`car_id`)
```

I think that will help others too.

Comment: You forgot to declare your RDBMS and version, which is crucial for a fitting solution. You write you want to *update `the_cars.car `*, but  the query tries to update `customer.car`. Please clarify by [editing your question.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/153957/edit)

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the usage of the dreaded backticks

Answer (score 2):

Your backticks indicate **MySQL**, where [this syntax works](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE customer AS c
JOIN   garages  AS g ON g.owner_id = c.id
JOIN   the_cars AS t ON t.car_id   = g.the_car_id
SET    c.car  = t.car
WHERE  c.car IS NULL;
```

In **Postgres** you would use a [different UPDATE syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE customer AS c
SET    car  = t.car
FROM   garages  AS g
JOIN   the_cars AS t ON t.car_id = g.the_car_id
WHERE  c.car IS NULL
AND    g.owner_id = c.id;
```

The `FROM` clause is not standard SQL.

You have to make sure that the query finds at most *one* car per customer, or the result is not deterministic.